# how to change default color scheme without mess up vi's color

Tags: macvim

Hey guys
I recently moved to macvim, It's great, when I add the theme: torth in the .vimrc. I found the color vi totally changed, It's either  the way of rails plugin, or the torth, like mixed color.

so how to set the startup color only affect macvim, I'm familiar with the vi's color with rails plug in, I don't want to mess it up.

BTW I how to toggle off the top tool bar in start up, It would be great,if someone can show me where to find the whole setup instruction.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MacVim honors "gvim" settings. GVim being the Gnome Vim gui variant that is rather prevalent on Linux.

This means that you should perhaps set overall settings specific to your user in "~/.vimrc", and override the ones you want in MacVim specifically by defining them in "~/.gvimrc".

It's up to you to decide what organizational method suits you best.

Comment: @VxJansonxV Thanks it works. And how to add some script to make the toolbar toggle off at default setting

Comment: That part, I have no idea. I'm not a very good GUI scripter :). So unless the MacVim documentation talks about how to collapse the toolbar, I don't have the answer to that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy `.vimrc` to `.vimrc.mac`

Change your theme color to `.vimrc.mac`,
and make an command alias of your macvim to read that vim config, like

```
alias='macvim -u ~/.vimrc.mac' <-- please note this syntax is using bash
                               <-- and macvim support -u like vim
```

Comment: Hey ajreal, thanks for your reply, where should I put alias='macvim -u ~/.vimrc.mac', I put it in .bash_profile, it doesn't work for me

Comment: @yozloy - some example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484429/profile-and-bashrc-doesnt-work-on-my-mac